# Pyomo: Getting keyerror: 4903576400

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt, optimal

I'm trying to solve an optimal control problem using pyomo, but I always get this keyerror which seems like a series of random numbers.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-926e5210dc1f> in <module>
     69 
     70 solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
---> 71 res = solver.solve(m)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    568             initial_time = time.time()
    569 
--> 570             self._presolve(*args, **kwds)
    571 
    572             presolve_completion_time = time.time()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyomo/opt/solver/shellcmd.py in _presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
    207         self._define_signal_handlers = kwds.pop('use_signal_handling',None)
    208 
--> 209         OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
    210 
    211         #

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py in _presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
    665             write_start_time = time.time()
    666             (self._problem_files, self._problem_format, self._smap_id) = \
--> 667                 self._convert_problem(args,
...
pyomo/repn/plugins/ampl/ampl_.pyx in genexpr()

pyomo/repn/plugins/ampl/ampl_.pyx in genexpr()

KeyError: 4903576400
```

Here is my code, my objective function is an integral, and the constraints are 4 ode, I am trying to use 'ipopt' to solve it.
I don't really know what's wrong with it...

```
import pyomo
from pyomo.environ import * 
from pyomo.dae import *

# parameter
r1 = 1.3195 * 10**(-6)
r2 = 1.885 * 10**(-5)
r3 = 0.19
r4 = 0.2

k = 0.00054

# initial value
S0 = 102028
E0 = 8251
I0 = 1843
R0 = 40435

m = ConcreteModel()

m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1000))
m.S = Var(m.t,initialize = S0)
m.E = Var(m.t,initialize = E0)
m.I = Var(m.t,initialize = I0)
m.R = Var(m.t,initialize = R0)
m.u = Var(m.t)

m.dSdt = DerivativeVar(m.S,wrt=m.t)
m.dEdt = DerivativeVar(m.E,wrt=m.t)
m.dIdt = DerivativeVar(m.I,wrt=m.t)
m.dRdt = DerivativeVar(m.R,wrt=m.t)

def ode1(m,t):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dSdt[t] == -r1*m.S[t]*(1-m.u[t])*m.E[t] - r2*m.S[t]*(1-m.u[t])*m.I[t]
m.odeS = Constraint(m.t,rule=ode1)

def ode2(m,t):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dEdt[t] == r1*m.S[t]*(1-m.u[t])*m.E[t] + r2*m.S[t]*(1-m.u[t])*m.I[t] - r3*m.E[t]
m.odeE = Constraint(m.t,rule=ode2)

def ode3(m,t):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dIdt[t] == r3*m.E[t] - r4*m.I[t]
m.odeI = Constraint(m.t,rule=ode3)

def ode4(m,t):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.dRdt[t] == r4*m.I[t]
m.odeR = Constraint(m.t,rule=ode4)


def myintegral(model,t):
    return k * model.I[t] + model.u[t]**2

m.o = Integral(m.t, wrt=m.t, rule=myintegral) 

def myintegral(m,t):
    return m.o
 
m.obj = Objective(rule=myintegral,sense=minimize)
m.pprint()

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
res = solver.solve(m)
```

I learned all the things by myself but was actually not that thorough, and I really need your help...

Comment: this might help u https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/#what-a-python-keyerror-usually-means

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyError` is coming from the Pyomo "NL writer" (it translates your model into an AMPL NL file that the `ipopt` solver can read and optimize.  The specific cause is that your model has constraints that reference objects other than Vars, Params and native constants (in particular, you have `DerivativeVar` and `Integral` objects).  This is admittedly a poor error message, and has been resolved by a rewrite of the NL writer (available in Pyomo >= 6.4.2, but will not become the default until 6.5).

You can resolve the error by *transforming* your model from a DAE into an NLP before sending it to a solver.  There are several transformations available; see the [DAE extension documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modeling_extensions/dae.html#discretization-transformations) for more information and examples.

Comment: That's helps a lot! Thx!